# Swift JSON Decoder

Tags: swift

Happy Easter!

I'm building an application to take in 3 different JSON files. Each of which are comprised of the same numbers as options to win a game(darts outs).

Example:

```
{
    "checkoutOptions1": [
        {
            "170": {
                "out": "T20 T20 DB"
            },
            
            "167": {
                "out": "T20 T19 DB"
            },
            
            "164": {
                "out": "T20 T18 DB"
            },
            
            "161": {
                "out": "T20 T17 DB"
            },
            
            "160": {
                "out": "T20 T20 D20"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

The other 2 files are the same numbers but the out string given is completely different.

I have a struct called "Out" which allows for the "out" to be taken in from the json file in question.

```
struct Out: Codable {
    let out: String
}
```

My Bundle decoder is defined as follows:

```
extension Bundle {
    func decode(_ file: String) -> [String: Out] {
        guard let url = self.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil) else {
            fatalError("Failed to locate \(file) in bundle.")
        }
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
            fatalError("Failed to load \(file) from bundle.")
        }
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        
        guard let loaded = try? decoder.decode([String: Out].self, from: data ) else {
            fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle.")
        }
        
        return loaded
    }
}
```

It's not working. This is the first time I'm dealing with JSON decoder. Looking for some insight to see if I have the right idea or not. TIA

Comment: Getting this error on compile: CheckOUTS/Bundle-Decodable.swift:21: Fatal error: Failed to decode CheckoutOption1.json from bundle.
2022-04-17 19:09:56.441590-0400 CheckOUTS[2236:86917] CheckOUTS/Bundle-Decodable.swift:21: Fatal error: Failed to decode CheckoutOption1.json from bundle.

Comment: If this is your own json files then I think you should edit them and remove any irrelevant information you don’t need.

Comment: **NEVER** use `try?` (with a question mark) until you are able to debug yourself. Even if you are, it's almost always recommended to use a proper `do`/`try`/`catch` and the minimum work to print the error in console and read it if there is one thrown. Your error is not on compiling, it's on running (it's different).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson By irrelevant information, what are you referring to?  All of the data within is data that needs to be utilized

Comment: @Larme Thanks for the useful advice. Will add it to the pile of should knows

Comment: Ok, it just didn’t look that way. I got the impression you only wanted the `Out` struct

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I'm pretty sure that's what my problem is lol So if I wanted to set my data to a variable(given what I have) 170: T20 T20 DB, what is the "Correct" way to set up the json file?

Comment: I would use an array of dictionaries like `[{"key": "170", "out": "T20 T20 DB"}, {...}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your model (`Out`) does not match the json data that you show. Try something like this:

```
struct Checkout: Codable {
    var checkoutOptions1: [[String : Out]]
}

struct Out: Codable {
    var out: String
}
```

and

```
 guard let loaded = try? decoder.decode(Checkout.self, from: data) else {
        fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle.")
    }
```

EDIT-1: here is a simple example of how to use the models

```
struct Checkout: Codable {
    var checkoutOptions1: [[String : Out]]
}

struct Out: Codable {
    var out: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("testing")
            .onAppear {
                let json = """
{
    "checkoutOptions1": [
        {
            "170": {
                "out": "T20 T20 DB"
            },
            
            "167": {
                "out": "T20 T19 DB"
            },
            
            "164": {
                "out": "T20 T18 DB"
            },
            
            "161": {
                "out": "T20 T17 DB"
            },
            
            "160": {
                "out": "T20 T20 D20"
            }
        }
    ]
}

"""
                
                let data = json.data(using: .utf8)!
                let loaded = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Checkout.self, from: data)
                print("\n----> loaded: \(loaded?.checkoutOptions1) \n")
                
            }
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
extension Bundle {
    
    func decode<T: Codable>(_ file: String) -> T {
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil) else {
            fatalError("Could not find \(file) in the project")
        }
        
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
            fatalError("Could not load \(file) in the project")
        }
        
        do {
            let loadedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
            return loadedData
        } catch {
            print(error)
            fatalError("Could not decode \(file) in the project")
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("testing")
            .onAppear {
                let result: Checkout = Bundle().decode("Dart.json")
                print("\n----> result: \(result) ")
                print("\n----> checkoutOptions1: \(result.checkoutOptions1) ")
                print("\n----> first: \(result.checkoutOptions1.first) ")
                print("\n----> 170: \(result.checkoutOptions1.first?["170"]) ")
                print("\n----> 170 out: \(result.checkoutOptions1.first?["170"]?.out) ")
            }
    }
}
```

EDIT-2:

I have no idea about scoring darts games, but using @JoakimDanielson suggestion,
you could restructure your json data to this:

```
{
    "options": [
                {
                    "key": "170",
                    "out": "T20 T20 DB"
                },
                {
                    "key": "167",
                    "out": "T20 T19 DB"
                },
                {
                    "key": "164",
                    "out": "T20 T18 DB"
                },
                {
                    "key": "161",
                    "out": "T20 T17 DB"
                },
                {
                    "key": "160",
                    "out": "T20 T20 D20"
                }
            ]
}
```

and use this example code to decode it into more manageable structures.

```
extension Bundle {
    
    func decode<T: Codable>(_ file: String) -> T? {   // <-- here optional
        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: file, withExtension: nil) else {
            print("Could not find \(file) in the project")
            return nil
        }
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url) else {
            print("Could not load \(file) in the project")
            return nil
        }
        do {
            return try JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
        } catch {
            print("Could not decode \(file) in the project")
            return nil
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var options: [Option] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("load data", action: {
            if let checkout: CheckOut = Bundle().decode("Dart.json") {
                options = checkout.options
            }
        }).buttonStyle(.bordered)
        List {
            ForEach(options) { option in
                Text("key: \(option.key)  out: \(option.out) ")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CheckOut: Codable {
    let options: [Option]
}

struct Option: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id = UUID()
    let key, out: String
}
```

Comment: on Bundle Decoder. Cannot convert return expression of type 'Checkout' to return type '[String : Out]'

Comment: the code will return `Checkout` type, you need to adjust you code accordingly, and take the `[String : Out]` out of that. eg `func decode(_ file: String) -> Checkout { ....}`

Comment: Adjust the json file from out to Out? Take out the [String : Out] from where?

Comment: updated my answer with some code that shows how to "take out" what you want from the decoded results.

Comment: Alternative method Error: keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "checkoutOption1", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"checkoutOption1\", intValue: nil) (\"checkoutOption1\").", underlyingError: nil))
CheckOUTS/Bundle-Decodable.swift:48: Fatal error: Could not decode CheckoutOption1.json in the project
2022-04-20 01:30:47.352145-0400 CheckOUTS[18513:1064558] CheckOUTS/Bundle-Decodable.swift:48: Fatal error: Could not decode CheckoutOption1.json in the project

Comment: The first method is really helpful. Accessing the items within is going to be my next objective. Let me know what your thoughts are on the comment above. Thanks. If you can do a chat with me that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Good progress. Does the `Alternatively` work for you with the code `exactly` as shown, and with a data in a file (Dart.json) 
with `exactly` the data that you provided. The important part is the `Checkout` in 
`let result: Checkout = Bundle().decode("Dart.json")`. 
The code for `Alternatively`, works very well for me, as long as it is exactly as shown.
Note, the data should be: `checkoutOptions1` not `checkoutOption1`, notice the `s`. This is probably why you get an error. Sorry I don't do chats.

Comment: Ok sooooooo lol smh...after a long walk away from the computer, I was wondering why my json file(having never done one) was ```{ checkoutOptions1: [[{....},..,{.....}]] }```. I think its safe to say, I do not fully grasp what the variable taking in the decoded file looks like. I also do not know where the extra array brackets came from but I digress. It is working but just to clarify, my "decode" extension sets a variable to a dictionary of items with the key of "some# string" and a value of "some string" right? would it be easier to set the key to a number? Thanks for everything

Comment: updated my answer with an example of another approach for your data and code.

Answer (score 0):

It's always helpful to wrap the `decode` into `try catch` and print the error. The error would tell you where the problem is.
If you did it like this:

```
do {
  let loaded = try decoder.decode([String: Out].self, from: data )
  return loaded
} catch {
  print(error)
  fatalError("Failed to decode \(file) from bundle.")
}
```

then it would print the following:

```
typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "checkoutOptions1", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

Indeed, if you look closely then the structure of your JSON is actually like this: `[String: [[String: Out]]]`. The value of the `checkoutOptions1` is an array containing one dictionary of type `[String: Out]`.

So if you change your code to this:

```
let loaded = try decoder.decode([String: [[String: Out]]].self, from: data )
```

it will succeed, though the result won't be that easy to deal with since your `Out` structures would be buried few levels down in the dictionary.

One way to improve this is to define the following model:

```
struct Options: Codable {
    let checkoutOptions1: [[String: Out]]
}
```

and then change your decode line to this:

```
let loaded = try decoder.decode(Options.self, from: data)
```

The `loaded.checkoutOptions1[0]` will contain the dictionary of type `[String: Out]`

Comment: I think see what you mean. To better clarify this, The json file that I have returns an array of dictionary items? With that said, should I remove the array "checkoutOptions1" and just have it decode {"170" : "string"},.....} into a single variable?